# Remove week day names using DateUtils in android

Tags: android

I'm using **DateUtils.formatDateRange(context, mF, startMillis, endMillis, flags,
                        tz);** to format a date range. I have various flags to hide year, month day But no flag to hide day of week in formatted result.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Its clearly mentioned (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) : "If FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY is set, then the weekday is shown.", otherwise it should not show week day.

Comment: day of week would not show except your flags are including DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY

Comment: Thanks @AbhinavPuri